# In a formal document, may the hyphen be omitted from "e-mail"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Email” or “e-mail”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/email-or-e-mail)

For a formal document such as a CV, would it be acceptable to use the term "email", or is only "e-mail" acceptable?