# To "have" a sharp focus?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm unsure of which verb I can use in a sentence where I am talking about how something enables someone to have a sharp focus on an issue. Here is a sentence that are possible:

> It enabled him to have a sharp focus on the issue.

This sentence sounds a bit strange, though. I feel like I could replace "have" with a better verb. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It enabled him to sharply focus on the issue?

Comment: Yes sure! Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Is “laser-focused” a new word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77518/is-laser-focused-a-new-word)

> It enabled him to **laser-focus** on the issue.

Comment: I find "laser-focus" as a verb strange. Perhaps "It gave him a laser-like focus on the issue" or "It enabled him to focus on the issue like a laser beam" or "It enabled him to focus like a laser beam on the issue". Technically, none of these make any sense: one needs optics to bring laser beams, like beams of incoherent light, to a focus. – – Richard Kayser 5 mins ago   edit

Comment: @RichardKayser In the ELU question I referenced I see some more debate on the scientific correctness of this! Originally I was going to simply answer *sharply focus* but I thought this variant was a more "interesting" phrase!

Comment: It is more interesting. :-) I was thinking shark-like might be good, as in how sharks focus unrelentingly on their prey. The advantage is that the focus is built into / inherent in the shark. I've heard people use it, but I couldn't find any references. Thanks.

Comment: I actually think that's a variant that sounds a bit more "natural." Thanks for the suggestion!