# Should " we studied it both on- and off-site" have both hyphens?

Tags: grammaticality, suspended-hyphen

Should the phrase "we studied it both on- and off-site" have both hyphens?  Or would "we studied it both onsite and offsite" be better?

Comment: As it happens, Google Books doesn't index punctuation marks, so a search for [**both on and off site**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22both+on+and+off+site%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) matches all permutations. Obviously both your versions *are* used, but my impression from a cursory scan of the first few pages is that **on-** is hyphenated more often than not. On the other hand, I think it adds nothing to legibility, and it makes the text look unduly "fussy", so I probably wouldn't include that first hyphen myself (I don't much care what "style guides" say about such things).

Comment: @Fumble - For what it's worth, I would probably include the hyphen, to alert the reader that the word (in this case, _on_) is not a standalone preposition, but part of a hyphenated term to be completed further on in the sentence.

Comment: @J.R.: Each to their own, I guess. I just think it's obvious what's going on when you see the short sequence ***both** X **and*** followed by a hyphenated term. Also I just think it's *easier* to "suspend" my interpretation momentarily for a trivial little word like ***on*** (which is almost immediately resolved by ***off-***). With the more unusual fragment ***on-***, my "internal parser" stutters a bit because I'm already wondering what's going on before I get to the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular context, on-site and off-site need to be hyphenated.
Source: 
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on-site

The word *off* is not a prefix as it can stand alone as a word. This is the reason, there could exist other versions depending on the context. For example: "He went off duty" but "He made an off-record confession".

That said, there may be other contexts or constructions, where a hyphen may not be required, as per the comments from the language enthusiasts here.

(As the language evolves and when more and more users (more importantly writers) begin to use what was once considered inappropriate, it becomes 'the norm' and dictionaries are updated quickly. As some of our community members pointed out here: e-mail = email, on-line = online. All one can do is to change with the changing times.)

Comment: According to that one reference you've provided, it can be spelled with a hyphen. However, [language evolves](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/email-or-e-mail) – just think of words like on-line (now often spelled _online_). I can find a couple dictionaries that already spell _offsite_ sans the hyphen: [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/offsite) and [businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/offsite.html).

Comment: It's quite true that English, of all the languages, evolves rapidly thanks to its widespread usage around the globe. Top dictionaries such as Collins, Oxford, American English, Merriam-Webster's, Cambridge, etc. have these two terms hyphenated.

Comment: The *full* OED has two subdefinitions for ***off-site***. The first one is the *adjectival* usage before a noun usage *(off-site disposal)*, which by standard rules of English *has* to be either a hyphenated form, or a single word (which isn't all that common with ***onsite, offsite*** yet). The second OED subdefinition is for the *adverbial* usage (as per OP's here), for which they give three citations - one each for the single-word, hyphenated, and two-word forms. I'd call that a draw. (Or ***Full** OED* tops *Collins, Oxford, American English, Merriam-Webster's, Cambridge, etc* :)

Comment: @Sankarane - You've said more to me in your comment than you did to the O.P. in your answer. Perhaps you ought to elaborate in your answer some, instead of having merely one terse, authoritative-sounding sentence backed up with one dictionary URL.

Answer (score 2):

I would write the sentence without either hyphen and keeping the space between the words:

> We studied it both on and off site.

There is no need to hyphenate when the phrase is used plainly and not as a modifier. Compare your sentence with the following:

> We conducted both on- and off-site studies.

In the last sentence, "on-site" (implied) and "off-site" are used as modifiers of "study". If you would like another example consider the following:

> I go off duty in two hours.
>
> An off-duty cop foiled a robbery today.

Comment: On purely stylistic grounds I don't like the initial "orphaned hyphen", and ditching the other one as well is perfectly valid, as you say. I'd go so far as to say I *prefer* the two word form except for the "leading adjective" contexts you present. Obviously not all "writers" in Google Books agree, but maybe that's because they're into business, science, etc. (not the art of fine writing! :)

Comment: I think as a general rule, many people overhyphenate. I am willing to let it go as a matter of style, but I definitely have an opinion as to which style is better. There are a some cases where phrases that are not modifiers must be hyphenated -- e.g., contractions like will-o'-the-wisp, headless nouns like five-and-dime, and numbers like twenty-two -- but unless there is a good reason to hyphenate, I choose not to.

Comment: My very thinking. Sure, *will-o'-the-wisp* ain't never gonna survive without its hyphenation (and I quite like the quaintness of the apostrophe, though I wouldn't defend it as strongly as the one in, say, *seven o'clock*). Many of the "potentially-hyphenated" terms we get asked about here are really just intermediate forms on their way to becoming single words anyway. But I'm not sure that'll fully happen with ***onsite*** - when I compare it to ***onboard, aboard, shipboard***, for example, ***site*** just doesn't seem to fit the construction so well (there's no ***offboard***, I think! :).

Answer (score -1):

Ngram doesn't treat hyphenated compound words as hyphenated words; instead, it treats them as two words separated by a letter space. So instances of "off-site" in a Google Books search show up in Ngram charts as examples of "off site."

Even so, this Ngram chart of *off site* (red line) versus *offsite* (blue line) indicates that, for the population of books in the Google Books database that have been published each year since 1963, instances of *offsite* have been more frequent than instances of *off site* and *off-site* combined:

[image]

Though I'm by no means certain that the Ngram algorithm captures all (or even most) instances of *off-site*, the data indicating a substantial rise in the frequency of *offsite* between 1940 and 2000 seems strong. And as the frequency of instances of *offsite* grows, the case for including *offsite* as a legitimate alternative to *off-site* and *off site* gets stronger. (*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* [2003] does not mention the spelling *offsite* in its entry for *off-site*, even as a variant.)

The Ngram results for *on site* (red line) and *onsite* (blue line) over the same period are quite different:

[image]

The two Ngram charts suggest that *offsite* has made considerably more headway against *off-site* than *onsite* has against *on-site*. At the very least, the Ngram results might justify adding a third alternative to the poster's two original options of "We studied it both on- and off-site" and "We studied it both onsite and offsite"—namely,

> We studied it both on- and offsite.

Just as *online* began as *on line*, shifted over time to *on-line*, and eventually became fused as *online*, I expect that *onsite* and *offsite* will eventually become the dominant spellings of those two terms. Nevertheless, the Ngram charts above indicate that, although *offsite* may be well on its way to dominant status, *onsite* still has a serious deficit in popularity to overcome.

For what it's worth, the *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003), approves of hyphenating the first (truncated) term of a pair such as "on- and offsite" above:

> **7.89** *Hyphen with word space.* When the second part of a hyphenated expression is omitted, the hyphen is retained followed by a word space.
>
> > [Relevant example:] fifteen and twenty-year mortgages
>
> Omission of the second part of a solid compound follows the same pattern.
>
> > [Relevant example:] both over- and underfed cats