# Is it acceptable to write "mini-steps" or should it be "mini steps? Can it be "mini-mangoes" or must it be "mini mangoes"?

Tags: hyphenation

Is it wrong to use a hyphen after "mini" in the following cases? Why or why not?

1. All I can do is take mini-steps by the day.
2. These mini-mangoes are sweet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Email" or "e-mail"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/email-or-e-mail) See the reference to Knuth's work. Then check to see if _mini-step_ and/or _mini step_ are given in a reputable dictionary. If not, check for usage in a Google search. It may be that using a nonce term is so colloquial that it is risky in more formal registers.

Comment: A Google search for mini meaning (to avoid the cars) tells us Cambridge dictionary wants hyphens and Oxford dictionary does not. Take yor pick.

Comment: Mini is considered a reduced form of 'miniature'. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mini; should help the OP